# How to specify the ".erlang" to use when "erl" command is called?

Tags: erlang

The original `.erlang` contains `code:add_pathz("/Users/xxxxx/Documents/Project/CY2/keyboard/ebin").`
It is located at the `~/.erlang`.

The another erlang start file contains
`code:add_pathz("/Users/xxxxx/Documents/Project/CY2/keyboard/_build/default/rel/lib/keybord/ebin").`

I want to specify which `.erlang` to use, Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#configuration), it isn't.

> When Erlang/OTP is started, the system searches for a file named `.erlang` **in the user's home directory.**

Actually… I checked a bit and while you can't choose a *different* `.erlang`, you can disable its execution entirely by setting a different *home path* for your node, like this…

```erlang
/tmp$ cat ~/.erlang
io:format("This is ~~/.erlang~n").

/tmp$ erl
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

This is ~/.erlang
Eshell V12.0.2  (abort with ^G)
1>
User switch command
 --> q
/tmp$ cat /tmp/.erlang
io:format("This is NOT ~~/.erlang~n").

/tmp$ erl -home /tmp
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Eshell V12.0.2  (abort with ^G)
1>
User switch command
 --> q
/tmp$
```

Comment: Another .erlang can't be used, I have to find other method to solve the problem.

Comment: Same trouble's question appeared already. rebar3 use "rebar3 shell" to solve the problem. https://rebar3.readme.io/discuss/56885d1de1f9a00d00350acb